# Part live-action, part animated TV show about kids in their high school(?) years who fought animated monsters

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon, animated-series

I'm looking for this one live-action/animated TV series that I watched in the early to mid 2010's (around that period of time at least).

It featured this group of three (or four) teenagers who would fight people who turned into animated monsters (I think Netflix picked up the series at one point).

The main cast consisted of two boys (*I DO know one of them was named **Iko** or something*, and I do remember a period in which Iko wasn't in the show for a bit because his actor was unavailable [they explained it in-story with how he went on vacation and show us this postcard, which I thought was funny]) and one girl. There might've been a third boy, but my memory's a little fuzzy.

Anyway, I also remember that almost all the teenaged protagonists turned into monsters themselves over the course of the series that the others had to fight, except one of them.

I've ruled out series like ***The Troop, Monster Warriors*** & ***ReBoot: The Guardian Code.***

Comment: Hi. Can you tell us more about the setting of the show? Like was it set in something resembling the real world? Did the kids attend school? Was it set in a fantasy world, or a futuristic world? Did the kids travel back & forth between worlds?

Comment: The title alone reminded me of Martin Mystery, even if it doesn't seem to fit the rest of the description.

Comment: Yes, it was set in something resembling the real world -- the only thing that was sci-fi-esque were the monsters, I believe. I'm pretty sure the kids attended high school (or at least some sort of school), as some of the episodes were set at school.

I don't think the kids traveled back & forth between worlds. It was more like this person would get 'corrupted' (I remember one of the protagonists turning because of  anger toward their fellow protagonists or something) and turn into an animated monster in which the other kids would have to fight in the real world.

Comment: It's not Martin Mystery either, though I thank you for the input :]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*[Team Toon](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2364348/)*, which released in 2013, seems to fit most of what you remember.

[image]

> Discovering that the "Psycho Squirrel" cartoon characters they draw can come to life, four friends pit their superheroes against a host of villains.

From [T.V. Tropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/WesternAnimation/TeamToon) it is noted that the show consists of four teenage kids, three boys and one girl. One of the boys is named Iko. The main setting is a high-school. The first season was [released on Netflix](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/tv/tv-news/netflix-new-releases-coming-june-803865/) on the 15th of June 2015. It is a Animated/Live-Action hybrid show.

Quoting some relevant snippets from T.V. Tropes:

> Four kids named Dylan, Sam, Ash, and Iko form a club called Team Toon, drawn together by their shared love of cartooning. In their club they produce the popular online viral series called "Psycho Squirrel", and they are popular at their school for their creation.
>
> Dylan discovers that they have the power to make their cartoon creations come to life and use it to form a superhero squad of the same name to fight rogue cartoon monsters that take over the minds of innocent humans.
>
> Episodes revolve around mysteries going in and around the school caused by monsters.